# How to add open source React libraries to Stack Overflow code snippet

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

I'm trying to add some React libraries ([`react-draggable`](https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable), [`react-xarrows`](https://github.com/Eliav2/react-xarrows), and [`react-zoom-pan-pinch`](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch)), which I normally would just install via `npm`, to the code snippet section on Stack Overflow. There is a button to add external `.css` and `.js`, but it doesn't let me do something similar to an `npm install`.

How do I do this? I'm trying to post a question but it would be helpful to have a functional code snippet.

EDIT: Added script issue with react-zoom-pan-pinch

```js
const App = () => {
  const handler = () => {
    console.log('handler firing');
  };
  
  const transformOptions = {
    limitToBounds: false,
    minScale: 0.25,
    maxScale: 3
  };
  
  return (
      <div>
      {/*<TransformWrapper
        options={transformOptions}
      >
        <TransformComponent>*/}
        <ReactDraggable
          defaultPosition={{x: 0, y: 0}}
          onStart={handler}
          onDrag={handler}
          onStop={handler}>
          <div>
            <div className="handle">Drag from here</div>
          </div>
        </ReactDraggable>
    {/*</TransformComponent>
      </TransformWrapper> */}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-draggable@4.2.0/web/react-draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tiendeo/react-zoom-pan-pinch@3.3.1/dist/index.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Depends on the library. Generally, you'll only be able to use the ones that have CDN links available somewhere. If you can't find any, you'll have to bundle and host it yourself.

Comment: Oh okay. I tried putting codesandbox links in my question but people keep flagging it, so I'm trying to do it with the code snippet.

Comment: You can use codesandbox links; you just have to include the corresponding source code on Stack Overflow as well. From [ask]: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but **also copy the code into the question itself**." This makes the minimal in "minimal, reproducible example" very important.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both react-draggable and react-zoom-pan-pinch have links on CDNs. Here's an example of how you'd use react-draggable in a Stack Snippet:

```js
const App = () => {
  const handler = () => {
    console.log('handler firing');
  };
  return (
    <ReactDraggable
      axis="x"
      handle=".handle"
      defaultPosition={{x: 0, y: 0}}
      position={null}
      grid={[25, 25]}
      scale={1}
      onStart={handler}
      onDrag={handler}
      onStop={handler}>
      <div>
        <div className="handle">Drag from here</div>
        <div>This readme is really dragging on...</div>
      </div>
    </ReactDraggable>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-draggable@4.2.0/web/react-draggable.min.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

The important part is to add in the `<script>` that defines the library *after* the React scripts are defined in the HTML.

For react-xarrows, you can do something similar, except with the following link:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tiendeo/react-zoom-pan-pinch@3.3.1/dist/index.min.js

I found these by googling `"<package name>" cdn`.

That said, while having a live Stack Snippet is *helpful* for those reading your question, so they can just press "Run" and see the issue(s) for themselves without having to open up an IDE, setup a workplace, and install stuff on their own - remember having a live example isn't *necessary*. As long as you put enough code in the question such that someone reading it could set up a project, paste in the code, and reproduce the issue, the question will still be fine (that's how all non-frontend questions are, after all).

Comment: Hi so I'm having trouble using the `react-zoom-pan-pinch` cdn. I have edited the post to show the issue. It seems like this doesn't work for some reasons

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tiendeo/react-zoom-pan-pinch@3.3.1/dist/index.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: @PTN I think the best thing to do would be to raise an issue on their GitHub repo (https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch) unless it's exclusively a Stack Snippet problem.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 okay I'll do that then

Comment: @PTN Actually, once I look at the error in DevTools (`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at jsdelivr-header.js:7`) it seems like it might be only Stack Snippets?

Comment: Never mind, it's not - https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/xsu24z95/

Comment: Whatever is doable on a plain HTML page is also doable in Stack Snippets, with the exception of the few things the sandboxed iframe forbids (like Local Storage). I wonder how the react-zoom-pan-pinch `.js` is intended to be used, maybe you're supposed to use it during development with Node and pack it with your app with Webpack or something?

Comment: I have posted an issue on their Github site

Comment: @PTN maybe post the link to that issue here as well

Comment: Here's the link: https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/154